# Seagate Expansion external drive not recognised in Windows 8.1

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, storage

Can someone PLEASE tell me why my Seagate Expansion external hard-drive is NOT recognised in Windows 8.1?  It worked perfectly on my other Win 7 Pro laptop, I just bought a new laptop with Win 8.1,and the drive doesn't appear on the "This PC" page. Device Driver says the Seagate is connected and working perfectly, Driver Update says the drivers are up-to-date and working, but the drive doesn't show on "This PC" Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Usually if drivers are installed correctly and device is reported as functional, but not mounted it is the case of drive letter not being assigned or conflicting. It is a common issue in Windows operations systems.

Try following:

- Open `"Run"` dialog
- Run `Diskmgmt.msc`
- Select the partition of your external hard drive
- Right click and in context menu choose `"Change Drive Letter and Paths"`
- Select a drive letter that is not used by any other drive
- Click OK

This should resolve the problem

You can find more detailed instructions with pictures [here](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-drive-letter-in-windows-8-1/).